# Как можно изменить положение иконок в списке?

Tags: css

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url(/images/bg/list.png);
}

li {
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettin Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettin</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettin</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettin</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettin</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettin</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettin</li>
</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

добавил свою иконку к тегу ul через list-style-image: и смотрится оно так словно они не на одной линии как можно опустить немного иконки?

Comment: иконки вместе с li ведь двигаются

Comment: добавьте свой код суда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня такой вариант. ul точки скрываем и уменьшаем отступ. Картинки вставляем на фон li сдвигаем их вниз `no-repeat 0px 3px;`, а сам текст сдвигаем вправо.

```css
.ul1 {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding-left:18px;
}
.ul1 li {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="20px" y="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve" height="20px" width="20px"><g><circle fill="red" r="10" id="sun" cx="10" cy="10" /></g></svg>') no-repeat 0px 3px;
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1">
<li><div>123</div></li>
<li><div>123 ffffffffffff fggggggggggggggggggf ffffffffffffffffffff fffffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffffff</div></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li><div>123</div></li>
<li><div>123 ffffffffffff fggggggggggggggggggf ffffffffffffffffffff fffffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffffff</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучше вместо маркера сделайте иконку фоновым изображением или псевдоэлементом `:before` для `<li>`. Тогда проще будет манипулировать ее положением.